# VBA Compare positions of two words in a Word document

Tags: vba, ms-word, cursor-position

I'm writing a module for defining acronyms in Word documents. The script gets the acronym and definition from an Excel document. What I'm having trouble with is comparing the location of the first instance of the acronym with the location of the first instance of the full definition.
Ultimately, I need to make sure the first instance of the acronym occurs immediately after the first instance of the definition, enclosed in parentheses. After this is done, the script will need to remove subsequent instances of the definition, so I also need to figure out how to remove all but the first instance of a definition.

The end result should look something like this:

> ....This document is about software as a service (SaaS). SaaS is software that is hosted by someone else. Rather than installing it on your own computer, you access it through a Web browser. There are many types of SaaS.
>   ....

How can I get the positions of these two elements and or compare their positions?

In the example above, how would I find the first instance of "SaaS" and make sure it occurred exactly two positions after (space, open parentheses) the definition (assuming the definition actually appears in the document)?

```
'Selects first instance of acronym. Get start and end positions of first instance of acronym.
    Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory
    Selection.Find.Execute Acronym 'Acronym is a variable. Now that it's selected, I need to get it's start position (or the position of the cursor if the cursor is at the start of the acronym) or find a way to compare it's position to the UserSelection variable.

    'Is the definition in the document?

        'If no, add definition before first instance of acronym.

        'If yes, get start and end positions of first instance of definition.

    'Is end position of first instance of definition adjacent to start position of first instance of acronym? If not, which is first?

        'If definition is first, add acronym behind definition.

        'If acronym is first, add definition in front of acronym and delete remaining instances of definition.

    'Highlights all instances of the acronym in green
        With ActiveDocument.Content.Find
            .MatchCase = True
            .MatchWholeWord = False
            With .Replacement
                .Highlight = True
            End With
            .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll, Wrap:=wdFindContinue, FindText:=Acronym, ReplaceWith:=Acronym
        End With
```

Any help or insight would be appreciated, as I'm completely at a loss and having no luck with Google.

-Vince

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the following code snippet can help you:

```
Sub example(acronym, definition)

    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Replacement.Text = ""
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindStop
        .Format = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With

    ActiveDocument.Range(0, 0).Select      ' go to beginning of document
    Selection.Find.Text = acronym
    Selection.MatchSoundsLike = False
    If (Not Selection.Find.Execute) Then
        ' acronym not found in this document
        Exit Sub
    End If

    ActiveDocument.Range(0, 0).Select      ' go to beginning of document
    Selection.Find.Text = definition
    Selection.MatchCase = False
    Selection.MatchSoundsLike = True

    While (Selection.Find.Execute)
        '
        Selection.Delete                    ' delete all definitions
        '
    Wend

    ActiveDocument.Range(0, 0).Select       ' go to beginning of document
    Selection.Find.Text = acronym
    Selection.MatchSoundsLike = False
    If (Selection.Find.Execute) Then
        Selection.InsertBefore "(" & definition & ")"
    End If

End Sub
```

Note: I also found that authors make mistakes in the definitions (minor variations) and even an extra unintended space messes up the find.

Comment: Thanks @Paul Ogilvie. Very helpful. I agree about authors making minor variations, but this will greatly help our editors make sure acronyms are properly defined, especially given that the vast majority of acronyms aren't defined by the authors of our documents. Running this program and then spending five minutes cleaning up in track changes is much better than spending 2-4 hours defining acronyms.